# Custom indeterminate progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I successfully have implemented this progress
[image]

Using animation-list with resources like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But problem is, that i can't impement half-heighted progress with this resources.

I have tried half-heighted resources with gravity centered vertically like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

But the result was 
[image]

Android pushed this progress to bottom.
Any ideas how can I center my half-heited progress? Thx in advance.

@Antoine Marques
I have tried nine-patch drawables, but i get somethink like this
[image]

And here is my animation-list:

```
<item android:duration="200" android:drawable="@drawable/progressbar_indeterminate1_0" />
```

And resource example: 
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the nine-patch idea wasn't good. Anyways, the implementation you made cannot work : strechable areas of a nine-patch are indicated at left and top. The bottom and right sides of a nine-patch indicate the content delimitation inside the drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is wrapping your custom progress drawable inside a `ScaleDrawable` :

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/my_custom_progress"
    android:scaleGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:scaleHeight="100%"
    android:scaleWidth="100%" />
```

Comment: Strange. What's the drawable that's scaled ? My first idea of using a `NinePatch` was bad. Besides, i believe what you obtain could come from putting the nine-patch inside this scale. Did you try putting your original drawable inside this scale drawable ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. Really have no ideas how to fix this. I can send your example of my test project if you interested in

Comment: If you want, i'll have a look and try to figure out some workaround.

Comment: Thx, in advance. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lux7ks98gyhvfas/PagingAdapter.zip

Comment: I'm currently making a test. I just noticed that in fact the progress isn't a single color, but the background being awfully horizontally streched, i'll see if i find a workaround.

Comment: Yes, it was after I have wrapped items inside scale

Comment: Here's a successful test : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44883890/PagingAdapter%202.zip. What was wrong : 1) the resource `progressbar_indeterminate1_0` has bounds widder than its content. So i used `progressbar_indeterminate1`. 2) Custom drawable are bitmaps, so if used inside another drawables, the option `tileMode="repeat"` had to be activated (it seems that progress drawable set it auto when a sole bitmap is given to it).

Comment: Then you just resize the `ProgressBar` wider or lower to have a little or large progress : the progress is clipped or repeated accordingly. (For now i see than a too big bar result in the progress being clamped, not repeated, so another option has to make it work, but you'll have to dig a little).

Comment: Thx, a lot. Found the same solution about height regulation

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how you made it. Could you please explain ?

Comment: I just made a simple trick with view height and negative margins. Here is the sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/ics1ic90msbrsfe/PagingAdapter.zip